# NestJS MongoDB validators not works

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I try to use validation in schema below

```js
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

@Schema({
  validateBeforeSave: true,
})
export class User extends Document {
  @Prop({
    unique: [true, 'login field must be unique'],
    required: [true, 'login field must be defined'],
  })
  login: string;

  @Prop({
    required: [true,'password required'],
    minlength: 4,
  })
  password: string;

  @Prop({
    type: Date,
  })
  createdAt: Date;

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

But nothing happened when I've saved a new user without password.

What could be the problem?

Comment: I had the problem `@Prop({ required: true })` didn't make sure the underlying value exists when being created. Adding `validateBeforeSave` explicitly seems to fix the problem. Unrelated to operators problem but might be helpful for others using @nestjs/mongoose. `@Schema({ validateBeforeSave: true })`

Answer (score 3):

A bit late to the party but for what it's worth you can solve this by adding a  validator to your "Prop" decorator like:

```
 @Prop({type: String, validate: {
        validator: (value) => Promise.resolve(value.length > 4),
        message: 'Password validation failed'
    }})
password: string;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to call a method `validate` on model, like:

```js
const User = db.model('User', userSchema);
const user = new User();

user.email = 'test@test.co';
user.name = 'test';
user.validate().catch(error => {
  assert.ok(error);
});
```

Check documentation [Mongoose Validation](http://%20https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html), even if they say it will works on `save` method, I will just call `validate` before to have 100% sure, they check it.

Comment: I don't now how  I can do this with Nestjs. Besides I set `validateBeforeSave: true,` in decorator

Comment: Can't you just call this method before save?

Comment: This is not an answer specific to nestjs @cojack

Comment: @MohamedImran there is no nestjs specific way of making validation on this framework.